# MySQL query returning no results when querying joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

I have a query to fetch a set of quizzes that are running that day. I want to make sure that the user hasn't already finished that quiz. The query I have is:

```
SELECT qi.qiId, qi.qiTitle, qi.qiDescription, qi.qiDate, qi.qiLeague, qi.qiType, qi.qiNumQuestions 
FROM quizzes qi 
LEFT JOIN quizOneDaySpecials qo 
ON qo.qoQuizId = qi.qiId 
AND qo.qoUserId = 11 
WHERE qi.qiLeague = 0 
AND qo.qoIsCompleted != 1 
AND qi.qiDate BETWEEN 1381878000 AND 1381964399
```

All the quiz details are in the `quizzes` table, and if a user has started or completed the quiz, then a record will exist in `quizOneDaySpecials`. However if the user hasn't started the quiz, no record will be in `quizOneDaySpecials`, and that's where my problem occurs.

`qo.qoIsCompleted` is `NULL` if a user hasn't started a quiz, and every time I run my query I get back no results. If I take out the `AND qo.qoIsCompleted != 1` then the quiz that the user hasn't started is returned as expected.

Why isn't my quiz being returned when I have the `qo.qoIscompleted != 1` check in? It seems perfectly valid, it doesn't equal one, as it's `NULL`.

Comment: Equating to NULL can give different logical results, depending on settings... to make it work regardless of settings, try changing that line to 'AND (qo.qoIsCompleted IS NOT NULL AND qo.qoIsCompleted != 1)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nulls evaluate to unknown and therefore won't match any operators other than IS NULL or IS NOT NULL. You could either add an OR statement to your qoIsCompleted or you can use IFNULL() function to check if it is null and if it is default the value to something like 0 so that it doesn't match.

```
AND IFNULL(qo.qoIsCompleted, 0) != 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare NULL values and non-null values directly.  Under default settings SQL Server doesn't know whether NULL is or isn't equal to 1.  It knows only that it's NULL. It looks like what you want is something like

```
WHERE IFNULL(qo.qoIsCompleted, 0) != 1  AND ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, checking for `NULL` is different than checking for a value.  You are negating your `OUTER JOIN` by including that in your `WHERE` criteria.  Move that check to the `JOIN` and then check for `IS NULL` in your `WHERE` criteria.

```
SELECT qi.qiId, qi.qiTitle, qi.qiDescription, qi.qiDate, qi.qiLeague, qi.qiType, qi.qiNumQuestions 
FROM quizzes qi 
    LEFT JOIN quizOneDaySpecials qo 
        ON qo.qoQuizId = qi.qiId 
            AND qo.qoUserId = 11 
            AND qo.qoIsCompleted = 1 
WHERE qi.qiLeague = 0 
    AND qi.qiDate BETWEEN 1381878000 AND 1381964399
    AND qo.qoQuizId IS NULL
```

Comment: I think this is it. But it may need that `AND qo.qoIsCompleted != 1` to become `AND qo.qoIsCompleted = 1`

Comment: @ypercube -- thanks, I believe you are correct and have edited the answer -- Cheers.